# How to pentest RMI

Tags: penetration-test, tools

I have a Swing client that communicates through T3 protocol (RMI) with a Server. Now I want to capture the requests and modify them (like HTTP in Burp or OWASP ZAP).
Is there any attack proxy for RMI/T3 or is the only possibility to use Wireshark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all searching such a tool:
I found EchoMirage, its a tiny tool that intercepts requests and lets you modify them. Really handy for application testing.
You can download it on sourceforge.